# Getting Laravel 5 to work with Angular's Syntax

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have looked around the web to find out how to get Angular `{{ variable }}` to work with Blade's syntax.

Few web sites say to do this to my Angular's: `@{{ var }}` but that does not work. I am trying to get a live search field to work.

In my page.blade.php file:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MyController">
    <input type="search" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="name in names | filter:search">
            @{{ name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
        <p>Tips: Try searching for <code>ann</code> or <code>lol</code></p>
</div>
</div>

<script>

function MyController($scope) {
$scope.names = [
'Lolita Dipietro',
'Annice Guernsey',
'Gerri Rall',
'Ginette Pinales',
'Lon Rondon',
'Jennine Marcos',
'Roxann Hooser',
'Brendon Loth',
'Ilda Bogdan',
'Jani Fan',
'Grace Soller',
'Everette Costantino',
'Andy Hume',
'Omar Davie',
'Jerrica Hillery',
'Charline Cogar',
'Melda Diorio',
'Rita Abbott',
'Setsuko Minger',
'Aretha Paige'];
}

</script>
```

I only get the search field to show but nothing else. The link is here that I copied: http://jsfiddle.net/r26xm/1/

PS: I am new to Angular and Laravel

Comment: I assume that no names are showing?  Which version of angular are you using?  Starting around 1.3, using global functions as controllers is no longer supported.  You will need to create your controller in a module.

Comment: @Cerad Im using 1.3.15. How to do that?

Comment: Being new to both is kind of a double whammy.  Why not start by learning the basics of one?  Use control-u to see what the browser is actually getting.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the way angularjs display the variables by interpolation.

Here is an example of how to do it:

```
<script>
  var customInterpolationApp = angular.module('customInterpolationApp', []);

  customInterpolationApp.config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
  });


  customInterpolationApp.controller('DemoController', function() {
      this.label = "This binding is brought you by [[ ]] interpolation symbols.";
  });
</script>
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="DemoController as demo">
    [[demo.label]]
</div>
```

Here is angularjs page explaning the [$interpolateProvider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$interpolateProvider)

Comment: Have you tried your method? Your exact answer do not work for me. The "string" never showed, only "//demo.label//"

Comment: Have not tried in Laravel, but this should work for sure. Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/5FRuCXy0SXnIP1h5ZxE0?p=preview . You can try and change // with [[ for startSymbol and ]] for endSymbol

Comment: Yes you are right, with // does not work, but I have just tried in laravel with [[ for startSymbol and ]] for endSymbol and it is working as expected

Comment: I don't recommend //, since under the hood this is all being converted into Javascript, and those are comments.

Answer (score 0):

Just place an @ at the beginning of the blade tags to tell blade you want the tags to just pass through. This is part of blade, not AngularJS. What version of Laravel are you using?

```
@{{some info}}
```

Will result in

```
{{some info}}
```

On your final form

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that angular 1.3 no longer support global functions as controllers.  http://wildermuth.com/2014/11/11/Angular_1_3_and_Breaking_Change_for_Controllers

So find a more up to date tutorial and use something like:

```
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('MyController',['$scope',function($scope) 
  {
    $scope.names = ['Lolita Dipietro','Annice Guernsey'];
  }
]);
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

This is not Laravel specific.  You can this kind of stuff working without any backend at all.  Just make an index.html file and serve it up.

Comment: All answers maybe working but it's a conflict with Laravel's Blade.

Comment: I don't know what that means.